# Completely disable module

Tags: magento2, module

I know you can disable Magento2 module output in the admin interface, but I'd like to remove some modules (eg. wishlist, RSS, newsletter) completely. We don't need them and I'd expect Magento to be a little faster if less code has to be loaded.
So I disabled the modules using `bin/magento module:disable --force`, but that broke some frontend pages like the customer dashboard.
How can I prevent the theme from trying to load a disabled module? I don't understand why Magento is so modular if disabling a module can break the site...

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete folder app/code/YourVendor/YourModule
2. Run the command:

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   ```
3. If you are in developer mode that is it. If you are in production then run:

   ```
   php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
   ```

Now you are all set.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that in the admin panel in configuration , advanced, advance , find your module and disable it in the drop down menu and save.

Comment: It would be really nice if you could actually read the question before you take the time to answer